# Zoom brightness missconfiguration when sharing my screen

Tags: arch-linux, brightness, zoom

I have a fresh Arch linux installation (it's my first time on Arch I work mostly on Oracle Linux), so far I have my windowing system working (I'm using Xmonad + Lightdm) just fine, I also changed the **/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness** to basically match the maximum brightness, the problem comes when screen sharing on [Zoom](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/zoom) meetings. In that case my screen brightness decays a lot for me and for the shared content.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find useful stuff on Google which can tell me a little bit more about my problem or a potential solution. Need help here.

Does anyone knows why this happens?